# "AND", "OR" with Like operator using Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('customer.*, feedback.*,feedback.id as fid');
$this->db->join('customer', 'customer.feedbackID = feedback.id', 'left outer');
$this->db->where('feedback.retail_id', $this->session->userdata('store_id'));
$this->db->where('feedback.fb_date BETWEEN "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('fromdate'))) . '" AND "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('todate'))) . '"');
$extra_where = explode(' ', $post_parameter);
foreach ($extra_where as $value) {`
        `$this->db->or_like('feedback.comments', $value);`
}
$this->db->like('feedback.comments', $this->session->userdata('search_text'));
$data['data'] = $this->db->get('feedback')->result();
```

My Question, I am using `OR`, `AND`, like operator then data is not fetching properly.

MySQL Query :

```
SELECT `customer`.*, `feedback`.*, `feedback`.`id` as fid
FROM (`feedback`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `customer` ON `customer`.`feedbackID` = `feedback`.`id`
WHERE `feedback`.`retail_id` =  '1'
AND `feedback`.`fb_date` BETWEEN "2015-08-01" and "2015-08-31"
AND  `feedback`.`comments`  LIKE '%Stock%'
OR  `feedback`.`comments`  LIKE '%not%'
OR  `feedback`.`comments`  LIKE '%Found%'
```

Example: Fetch the data for aug then data should be matching, the Stock has not found keys and only for month of aug, But is showing the data of June as well because "`not`" key word exist in that row.

I am getting confuse sue to `OR` and `AND` at what time I have to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = $this->db->query(
    "SELECT customer.*,feedback.*,feedback.idas fid
    FROM feedback AS feedback
    LEFT OUTER JOIN customerONcustomer.feedbackID=feedback.id
    WHERE feedback.retail_id=  '1'
    AND feedback.fb_date BETWEEN '2015-08-01' AND '2015-08-31'
    AND feedback.commentsLIKE '%Stock%'
    OR feedback.commentsLIKE '%not%'
    OR feedback.commentsLIKE '%Found%'");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: Thank You for help .... But didn't work sir.... it is fetching the data of July, aug,spet as well...

Comment: @phpdeveloperci add your correct Query to this. this work fine. Not mine

Comment: yes there were some correction, Done that as well... But not working sry sir......

Comment: So actually problem is with your SQL Query

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
$this->db->select('customer.*, feedback.*,feedback.id as fid');
$this->db->join('customer', 'customer.feedbackID = feedback.id', 'left outer');
$this->db->where('feedback.retail_id', $this->session->userdata('store_id'));
$this->db->where('feedback.fb_date BETWEEN "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('fromdate'))) . '" AND "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post('todate'))) . '"');

$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->like('feedback.comments',$this->session->userdata('search_text'));
$extra_where = explode(' ', $post_parameter);
foreach ($extra_where as $value) {`
        `$this->db->or_like('feedback.comments', $value);`
}
$this->db->group_end()
$data['data'] = $this->db->get('feedback')->result();
```